# Conditional Join statement in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, case

I want to implement conditional join statement in a way if first condition pass then select record based on first condition else go to second join condition..

```
Select 
    col1, Col2, Col3, TableB.Column1, TableB.Column2 
from 
    TableA
JOIN 
    TableB ON (TableA.col1 = TableB.Column1
               TableA.col2 = TableB.Column2
               TableA.col3 = TableB.Column3)
              OR //second OR
              (
               TableA.col1 = TableB.Column1
               TableA.col2 = TableB.Column2
               TableB.Column3 IS NULL
              )
             OR //Third OR
              (
               TableA.col1 = TableB.Column1
               TableA.col3 = TableB.Column3
               TableB.Column2 IS NULL
              )
```

If condition one passed, query should not go to second OR condition and I should get one row as output only.

Comment: Can't you just  use union all?

Comment: Union all is not going to help here. Currently i am getting output(2 rows) as below
col1      col2      col3
a           b            c
a           NULL     c

but i want output in one single row as first condition is passed no need to jump on second OR condition. So expected output is 
col1      col2      col3
a           b            c

Comment: What if first set of conditions fails but second one succeeds? Sould the query return rows satisfying the third set of conditions as well?

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your requirements correctly, then the following query is what you are looking for:

```
SELECT col1, Col2, Col3
FROM (
  SELECT col1, Col2, Col3,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY seqNo) AS rn 
  FROM (
    -- Query no. 1
    SELECT col1, Col2, Col3, 1 AS seqNo 
    FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.col1 = TableB.Column1 
                        AND TableA.col2 = TableB.Column2
                        AND TableA.col3 = TableB.Column3

    UNION ALL

    -- Query no. 2
    SELECT col1, Col2, Col3, 2 AS seqNo
    FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.col1 = TableB.Column1 
                        AND TableA.col2 = TableB.Column2
                        AND TableB.Column3 IS NULL

    UNION ALL

    -- Query no. 3
    SELECT col1, Col2, Col3, 3 AS seqNo 
    FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.col1 = TableB.Column1 
                        AND TableB.Column2 IS NULL
                        AND TableA.col3 = TableB.Column3 ) AS t 
) AS s
WHERE s.rn = 1
```

The above will return the first non-empty set of the three separate queries being `UNION`ed.

This means if query no. 1 returns a non-empty set, then the rows of this set *and only these* are going to be returned. Otherwise rows of query no. 2 are returned, etc.

Comment: will it not always return the `seqNo` `1`, i.e. results from the first query.. as the result?

Comment: It will always return rows having `rn=1`, i.e. rows of the first non-empty set. If the first query fails to return any records, then there are no `seqNo=1` records.

Comment: Actually, it will only ever return the first result from the UNIONed resultset - to work as required, you should replace `ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY seqNo)` with `RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, Col2, Col3 ORDER BY seqNo)`

Comment: you are hard-coding `seqno`..so no matter what..results from the `first query` would be returned..based on the `order by` in `row_number()`

Comment: @vkp: He's selecting on `s.rn`, not `seqno`.

Comment: @MarkBannister..yes and that is derived from `seqNo` right?

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: You need the `PARTITION BY` clause in the `OVER (...)` arguments, otherwise the query will only ever return one row.

Comment: @MarkBannister Have a look [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb630f/3). `RANK` is going to be the same for all records that belong to the same slice.

Comment: @vkp Have a look at the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/bb630f/3) I've setup. It clarifies what happens if first set is empty.

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos: I think we have a different understanding of what the OP wants - I've added an answer, based on my understanding.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood the requirements correctly, the following should return the desired results:

```
SELECT col1, Col2, Col3, column1, column2
FROM (
  SELECT col1, Col2, Col3, column1, column2,
         RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY col1, Col2, Col3 ORDER BY seqNo) AS rn 
  FROM (
    -- Query no. 1
    SELECT col1, Col2, Col3, column1, column2, 1 AS seqNo 
    FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.col1 = TableB.Column1 
                        AND TableA.col2 = TableB.Column2
                        AND TableA.col3 = TableB.Column3
    UNION ALL
    -- Query no. 2
    SELECT col1, Col2, Col3, column1, column2, 2 AS seqNo
    FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.col1 = TableB.Column1 
                        AND TableA.col2 = TableB.Column2
                        AND TableB.Column3 IS NULL
    UNION ALL
    -- Query no. 3
    SELECT col1, Col2, Col3, column1, column2, 3 AS seqNo 
    FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.col1 = TableB.Column1 
                        AND TableB.Column2 IS NULL
                        AND TableA.col3 = TableB.Column3 ) AS t 
) AS s
WHERE s.rn = 1
```

SQLFiddle [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/67fd5/5).